How to make a panel disappear or update widgets in panel upon each click of the map?

I am trying to create a panel that opens with each click near a point on the map.
I am running into an issue where a new panel opens up each click, covering the screen.
I am aware of the .unlisten() and .remove() function but I am unsure how to implement them.
Also https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ui_panels#absolute the last tutorial on this page seems to be what I need to do but now I am not sure how to take my code which reads the metadata of a feature near the clickpoint and creates widgets and adds a panel out of the onClick function.
// Usage example (assuming your `collection` and `point` are defined)
var clicker = Map.onClick(function(coords){

    var clickPoint = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat);
    print(clickPoint);

    var findNearestFeature = function(collection, clickPoint) {
        // Ensure point is a valid geometry
        var point = ee.Geometry(clickPoint); // Convert to geometry if needed
        // Apply the buffer method to the Point object.
        var pointBuffer = point.buffer({'distance': 50});
        // Filter the collection to features within the bounds of the point
        var filteredCollection = collection.filterBounds(pointBuffer);
        var feature = filteredCollection.first();

        var date = feature.get('Name');
        var description = feature.get('descriptio');
        var widgetDate = ui.Label({ value:date.getInfo(), style: {fontWeight: 'bold'}, });
        var Description2 = description.getInfo()
        print(Description2);

        var Description3 = Description2.split('Source(s):');
        // Extract the system date (YYYYMMDD) from the first token
        var Description4 = Description3[0];
        var splitlink = Description3[1].split('Geolocation(s):');
        var link1 = splitlink[0];
        var link2 = splitlink[1];
        print('token2', link2);
        print('token', link1);

        var widgetDescription = ui.Label(Description4);
        var linkOne = ui.Label('Source(s):');
        var LinkOne = linkOne.setUrl(link1);
        var linkTwo = ui.Label('Geolocation(s):');
        var LinkTwo = linkTwo.setUrl(link2);
        var pointclicked = ui.Panel({
            widgets: [widgetDate, widgetDescription, LinkOne, LinkTwo],
            style: {position: 'top-right', stretch: 'vertical', margin: '0px 8px'},
        });

        Map.add(pointclicked);

        // Return the first feature (nearest)
        return feature;
    };
    findNearestFeature(collection, clickPoint);// Adjust distance threshold here (optional)

});

JK I think I figured it out, using that link tutorial.
// APP
// Checkbox to show geoconfirmed data
var checkbox = ui.Checkbox('Show Geconfirmed Points', true);
checkbox.onChange(function(checked) {
    // Shows or hides the first map layer based on the checkbox's value.
    Map.layers().get(2).setShown(checked);
});

var GeconfirmedPanel = ui.Panel({
    style: {
        position: 'top-right',
        stretch: 'vertical',
        margin: '0px 8px'
    }
}).add(checkbox);

Map.add(GeconfirmedPanel);

// Usage example (assuming your collection and point are defined)
var clicker = Map.onClick(function(coords) {
    var clickPoint = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat);
    print(clickPoint);

    var findNearestFeature = function(collection, clickPoint) {
        // Ensure point is a valid geometry
        var point = ee.Geometry(clickPoint); // Convert to geometry if needed
        // Apply the buffer method to the Point object.
        var pointBuffer = point.buffer({'distance': 50});
        // Filter the collection to features within the bounds of the point
        var filteredCollection = collection.filterBounds(pointBuffer);
        var feature = filteredCollection.first();

        var date = feature.get('Name');
        var description = feature.get('descriptio');
        var widgetDate = ui.Label({
            value: date.getInfo(),
            style: {fontWeight: 'bold'},
        });
        var Description2 = description.getInfo();
        var Description3 = Description2.split('Source(s):');

        // Extract the system date (YYYYMMDD) from the first token
        var Description4 = Description3[0];
        var splitlink = Description3[1].split('Geolocation(s):');
        var link1 = splitlink[0].match('https:.*');
        var link2 = splitlink[1].match('https:.*');

        var widgetDescription = ui.Label(Description4);
        var linkOne = ui.Label('Source(s):');
        var LinkOne = linkOne.setUrl(link1);
        var linkTwo = ui.Label('Geolocation(s):');
        var LinkTwo = linkTwo.setUrl(link2);
        GeconfirmedPanel.widgets().set(1, widgetDate);
        GeconfirmedPanel.widgets().set(2, widgetDescription);
        GeconfirmedPanel.widgets().set(3, LinkOne);
        GeconfirmedPanel.widgets().set(4, LinkTwo);

        // Return the first feature (nearest)
        return feature;
    };

    findNearestFeature(collection, clickPoint); // Adjust distance threshold here (optional)

});

